# Pass PHP Array via jQuery Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I've got a php array:

```
$toField = explode(",", $ids);  //Which looks something like '24,25,26,29'
```

I want to pass this array via jQuery AJAX, with this:

```
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="hidden"  value="'.$toField.'">
  <input type="submit" id="sendMessage" class="faceboxSubmit" name="ok" value="Send Reply"/>
</form>
```

And here's my jQuery:

```
$("#sendMessage").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var senderID = <?php echo $usrID; ?>;
    var receiverID = $("#toField").val();
    $.ajax( 
{ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "replyMessage.php", 
    data: "senderID=" + senderID + "&subject=" + subject + "&message=" + message + "&receiverID=" + receiverID + "&threadID=" + thread_id,
    beforeSend: function() {
        $("#sendingMessage").show();
        },
            success: function() {
        alert("Success");
        }

         });    
    });
```

How can I pass the array, so that with the "replyMessage.php" page, I could take each ID from the Array, to do something like this:

```
    <?php 

    foreach ($_POST['receiverID'] as $receiverID) 
   { 
     mysql_query //etc...
   }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you probably want to use [`implode`](http://www.php.net/implode), and not explode, to construct your `$toField` variable ;-)

```
$ids = array(24, 25, 26, 29);
$toField = implode(',', $ids);
var_dump($toField);
```

Which would give you

```
string '24,25,26,29' (length=11)
```

You then inject this in the form ; something like this would probably do :

```
<input type="hidden"  value="<?php echo $toField; ?>">
```

*(Chech the HTML source of your form, to be sure ;-) )*

Then, on the PHP script that receives the data from the form when it's been submitted, you'd use [`explode`](http://php.net/explode) to extract the data as an array, from the string :

```
foreach (explode(',', $_POST['receiverID']) as $receiverID) {
    var_dump($receiverID);
}
```

Which will get you :

```
string '24' (length=2)
string '25' (length=2)
string '26' (length=2)
string '29' (length=2)
```

And, now, you can use thoses ids...

Answer (score 3):

```
<form id='myform'>
 <input type='hidden' name='to[]' value='1' />
 <input type='hidden' name='to[]' value='2' />

 .. etc ..
 .. rest of you're form ..
</form>
```

jQuery change the data: .. part to:

```
data: $('#myform').serialize()
```

Then in you're PHP:

```
foreach ( $_POST [ 'to' ] as $num )
{
 // do something with $num;
}
```

Something like this an option?

Answer (score 0):

you can get the string in the php code and separate it on the comma, then loop through the values.

https://www.php.net/split

Answer (score 0):

Few things going on I'd sort out:-

- You're missing the id 'toField' on your toField input element.
- You should be using implode() on the $id variable rather than exploding it.
- On the otherside you should be calling explode() on the recieverId string.

Answer (score 0):

just echo your array in a for each loop with some special characters like | &| .
if it is multi dimensional use each  character on both loops and echo it.
and by using some delimiter function change it back to array in java script